# Android custom keyboard background

Tags: android

How can set the background for the android custom keyboard,i want to set a image as the background for entire keyboard for the android device not for a single keyboard me tried with the attributes like android:keysBackground and android:background but it is not working while doing with the android:keysBackground attribute the image is present as the background for every keys, but i need to a single background for the keyboard like wallpaper plzzzzz help

Comment: I am also facing same problem, please share if you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

KeyboardView is a subclass of View class that has an attribute called android:background. Set this attribute to whatever image you want and it should work fine. If you have set keyBackground attribute then you might not be able to see it, to make background visible you need to play a little bit with your layout for instance, set key background opacity, or make key background completely transparent. I hope it would help. Cheers.

Comment: I use keyBackground but it doesn't show my picture on keys, in your answer you said we have to play with transparency, would you please explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

The attribute android:background for the keyboard view doesn't change the look of the keys it just changes the background of the whole keyboard. I think your problem is that the keys are opaque by default so you cant see the background behind the keys. To fix that you will have to set the android:keyBackground to a `Drawable` like a .png or nine patch `Drawable` that is partially or completely transparent. You might be able to set the `keybackground` to null to make it transparent but I haven't tried it so that might not work and it might crash. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the xml layout of the rootview of the keyboard that you are using. for example the relative layout with custom background

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rootview"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/custom">

<KeyboardView
                android:id="@+id/keyboard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:keyBackground="@drawable/key_background"
                android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/preview"
                android:keyTextColor="#000"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:popupLayout="@layout/keyboard_popup_layout"
                android:shadowRadius="0.0"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp">

            </KeyboardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```